# MPDF does not show table borders or anything related to table, just data

Tags: mpdf

I just need the simplest workaround way or at least reason why it does not work

I already figured out that bootstrap does not work with MPDF, so wrote a simplest piece of regular html code. But still, no table is being shown.

```
 <?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

  //html variable

  $data= '<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
    scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

  </head>
  <body>

//A Simple table
   <table >
   <thead>

   <tr>


     <th scope="col">ID</th>

   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody align="center">
 <tr ><td> 2413134</td><tr/>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>';


//outputing from here
$mpdf->WriteHTML($data);



$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a border via css:

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```